# Is there a silver bullet function in PHP that will clean a string so it's suitable for RSS?

Tags: php, rss

I have a lot of data that contains characters that will normally break RSS.  Is there a function or library in PHP that will handle these characters so they are suitable to be printed in an RSS Feed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Take a look at the comments, there are some `xmlentities` functions there you can use (since RSS is XML).

Answer (score 1):

RSS is simply XML. So the characters escaped by [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) should be sufficient or [htmlentities()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) escapes some extra characters, which might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use htmlentities() and it will encode the strange character in a strange encoding but it wouldn't break RSS.

Answer (score 0):

htmlentities() isn't enough. When I tried it, it left many things that broke IE's and Firefox's feed readers. I am sure others would break too. When I used xml_entities() posted by somebody at http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php, things that didn't work started to work.